# Unity 3D - User is filling in an survey and then automatically send an email

Tags: c#, scripting, unity-game-engine

In Unity 3D I want as the title says: A user is filling in an survey and then automatically send an email. I use Unity 3D.
I already have this c# script but I want the user of my game fill this in.

Script:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

using UnityEngine;

public class SendMail : MonoBehaviour {
    public string sender = "me@mymailaccount.com";
    public string receiver = "me@mymailaccount.com";
    public string smtpPassword = "mysmtppassword";
    public string smtpHost = "mail.mymailacount.com";

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start() {
        using (var mail = new MailMessage {
            From = new MailAddress(sender),
            Subject = "test subject",
            Body = "Hello there!"
        }) {
            mail.To.Add(receiver);

            var smtpServer = new SmtpClient(smtpHost) {
                Port = 25,
                Credentials = (ICredentialsByHost)new NetworkCredential(sender, smtpPassword)
            };
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
            smtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "I need a house, I have these planks."

That's essentially how your "question" sounds. No offense meant, but nobody will implement the feature for you. You'll need to flesh out your question a bit more. Do as much as you can by yourself, identify exactly what doesn't work, then ask specific questions.

SO has a nice [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).